# Pl sql installation

Tags: c, oracle

I have an application running in C/Pro*C and calling multiple packages in an Oracle database. How I can install modified packages without stopping my C/Pro*C application?

My application is a real time application and it is supposed to run all the time. 
Thanks in advance for helping me.

Comment: This comes down to your application architecture. If it's been designed for high availability then you're golden. Otherwise you'll need some downtime.

Comment: See some tips here - https://markhoxey.wordpress.com/2013/09/17/avoiding-ora-04068-existing-state-of-packages-has-been-discarded/  As @APC stated, you would need to trap for ORA-0406 errors, and re-try the call, or similar mechanism.

Comment: Thanks guys. The last article is very interesting!